# C# - Regex replace if not inside of quotes

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

Let's take this block of code:

```
string Val = "I like foo, baz and bar, they where before \"foo, baz and bar\"";

string[] first = {
    "foo",
    "baz",
    "bar"
};

string[] second = {
    "java",
    "php",
    "ruby"
};
```

Look that inside my Val string I have a text, I want to replace only the part which isn't inside of the quotes (\"), but if I do

```
Val = Regex.Replace(Val, first, second);
```

It just gives me

```
I like java, php and ruby, they where before "java, php and ruby"
```

While I expect

```
I like java, php and ruby, they where before "foo, baz and bar"
```

Can someone help to solve this problem? I didn't find any documentation explaining it.

Comment: Why don't you split your Val into 2 variables: Val1 = "I like foo, baz and bar, they where before" and Val2 = "\"foo, baz and bar\"" and replace text in Val2 before concatenating Val1 and Val2 into Val.

Comment: Why do you expect that result? `Regex.Replace`, replaces all found matches. And the documentation is called [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure you need Regex? This task doesn't seem fit for regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split on quotation marks and do the replace on every other string, then put the strings together:

```
string[] parts = Val.Split('"');
for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i += 2) {
  parts[i] = Regex.Replace(parts[i], first, second);
}
Val = String.Join("\"", parts);
```

Comment: +1 nice one. I was using `Select` and checked if an index is even to replace parts

Comment: Unless your quoted string has escaped quotes in it... :D

Comment: @Rawling: Then it depends on how they are escaped. If they are escaped VB style, i.e. by doubling them, then it's not a problem. :)