# Replace parts of string which are not surounded with quotes

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I am parsing a as3 code into json object and right now I need to remove all whitespaces which are not surrounded by quotes,but in future maybe add an option to replace multiple whitespaces with only one.

Example:

```
List<string> codeList = new List<string>();
codeList.Add("private    var   a:string = \"this    is string\"  ;");
codeList = FormatCode(codeList);
```

The output of `codeList[1]` should be :

```
 - privatevara:string=\"this    is string\";
```

or

```
 - private var a:string = \"this    is string\" ;
```

I would appreciate any help or ideas to solve the problem.

Comment: Can your quoted string contain escaped quotes?  And if so how would they be escaped?

Comment: The file I am parsing is an AS3 file but I don't expect any escaped quotes in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Regex replace if not inside of quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763056/c-sharp-regex-replace-if-not-inside-of-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to compress the spaces that are not inside of quotes.  Note this doesn't verify that quotes match up and doesn't work for escaped quotes.

```
public static string CompressSpacesOutsideQuotes(string input)
{
  bool quoted = false;
  bool spaceSeen = false;
  var builder = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (char c in input)
  {
    if (c == '"')
    {
      quoted = !quoted;
    }

    if (c == ' ' && !quoted)
    {
      spaceSeen = true;
      continue;
    }

    if(spaceSeen)
    {
      builder.Append(' ');
      spaceSeen = false;
    }

    builder.Append(c);
  }

  if (spaceSeen) builder.Append(' ');
  return builder.ToString();
}
```

For your example

```
Console.WriteLine(
    CompressSpacesOutsideQuotes("private    var   a:string = \"this    is string\"  ;"));
```

prints

```
private var a:string = "this    is string" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this works for you:

```
private void FormatCode(List<string> codeList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < codeList.Count; i++)
        {
            codeList[i] = FormatCode(codeList[i]);
        }
    }

    private string FormatCode(string code)
    {
        string formatted = String.Empty;
        MatchCollection matches = new Regex("\".*?\"").Matches(code);
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
            Match match = matches[i];
            string toFormat = i == 0 ? code.Substring(0, match.Index) : code.Substring(matches[i - 1].Index + matches[i - 1].Length, code.Length - match.Index);

            toFormat = String.Join(" ", toFormat.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
            formatted += toFormat + matches[i].Value;

            if(i == matches.Count - 1)
                formatted += String.Join(" ", code.Substring(match.Index + match.Length).Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        }

        return formatted;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Well... - juharr's answer looks somewhat more efficient :)

Comment: any progress so far? if you find juharr's or my answer helpful pls mark it as accepted - thx